# Best Practice - calling a create action from another controller

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am trying to store login stats, when a user logs in from within the account controller. I do not need to present this data to the user, it will be for admin purposes only.

What is the best way to achieve this.

So far I have a **GlobalStats** model and **GlobalStatsController**.

Based on what I have been reading, it's strange to call a controller from within another controller, normally they would return a view.  Is a service better suited for this? Or a separate method that I can call within this account controller.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What are the stats? If they are few simple numbers and don't change often during the session, then you can add them to the cookie as session variables. If they change often during the session, then fetch them from db for every page, and don't store them anywhere. If your question is how to do that in a central code, then you can use a child action and view component.

Comment: @RacilHilan The GlobalStats will contain various user information, such as LoginDate, ChangedPasswordDate, and potentially other information, so it can be used for reporting.

Comment: Assuming it is used in more than one report, you can use a child action and view component as I suggested.

Comment: @RacilHilan It's the saving of the data I am having an issue with.  Do I call the GlobalStatsController in the AccountController to save the GlobalStats?  I do not need to surface this data in a view at the monent.

Comment: If you don't need to display it, then what do you need it for? You need to add more details to your question so we can help you. As it stands now, I don't see any point in storing it anywhere.

Comment: @RacilHilan it's the saving of the data I am having an issue with.  This data is just for admin purposes, it can be queried directly from the table itself, we do not need to surface this to a view for the admin user, it's more of a log, sorry I should of added this to the question.

Comment: Yes, edit your question and add all relevant information to make it easier for others to help you. Actions, child actions, and view components are all to interact with views, not for log. If you only need to log in one controller, then use a private function in that controller to do the job and called it from the different actions. If you want to log from different controllers, then you can create a utility/helper class with functions (perhaps static) that you can call from all controllers.  You can put the model and functions in one GlobalStats class, or separate classes ex GlobalStatsHelper.